# Python flask app with Nginx and uWSGI gives Internal Server Error when writing it as class

Tags: python

I am building a API that uses flask. I am going to use uWSGI and NGINX in production. The API is working as it is, but I am trying to rebuild it to use classes. When I run it after I have build it as a class it gives me `Internal Server Error`.

**The following files are working:**

*src/server.py*

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/ping")
def ping():
    return "pong"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

*src/wsgi.py*

```
from src.server import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**When I try to build it as class then I get Internal Server Error**

*src/server.py*

```
from flask import Flask


class Main:
    app = Flask(__name__)

    def __init__(self):
        @self.app.route("/ping")
        def ping():
            return "pong"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

*src/wsgi.py*

```
from src.server import Main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.app.run()
```

Comment: "internal Server Error" is an HTTP error reported to client.  What's in your app logs/stderr?

Comment: I run it on Windows 10 with Docker Desktop, where is the logs file located?

Comment: I have no idea, it's your setup, not mine =)